# Web Socket behind proxy

Tags: websocket, proxy, apache2, spring-websocket

I have Spring Boot app with WebSocket running behind Apache 2. When trying connect I am getting the following error:

- Server Log:

  ```
  Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
  ```
- Client Log:[image]

Here is the Apache 2 config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin tom_marik@hotmail.com
ServerName www.languageexchange.eu

ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://www.languageexchange.eu:92/"
ProxyPass "/wss2/" "wss://www.languageexchange.eu:92/"

ProxyPass           /   http://31.31.74.54:92/
ProxyPassReverse    /   http://31.31.74.54:92/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /    /
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/languageexchange.log
LogLevel warn

RewriteEngine on
[END,QSA,R=permanent]
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/languageexchange.eu/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/languageexchange.eu/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/languageexchange.eu/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you host your server? On AWS there is a problem with WebSocket support when you use ELB in some modes.

Comment: It is just VPS with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have *mod_proxy_wstunnel* installed (*mod_proxy* and *mod_ssl* as well). Then in your Apache's configuration:

```
ProxyPass /ws2  ws://languageexchange.eu:92 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /ws2  ws://languageexchange.eu:92
ProxyPass /wss2 wss://languageexchange.eu:92 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /wss2  wss://languageexchange.eu:92
```

If this is a single machine it may be better to set *127.0.0.1* instead of *languageexchange.eu*, so:

```
ProxyPass /ws2  ws://127.0.0.1:92 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /ws2  ws://127.0.0.1:92
ProxyPass /wss2 wss://127.0.0.1:92 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /wss2  wss://127.0.0.1:92
```